# Error while changing label

Tags: objective-c, ios7.1, xcode5.1

```
- (IBAction)B1:(id)sender {

    LastView *New;   
    New.Connection1=@"Salut";
}
```

LastView is my class to a viewcontroller that has a label T1.
B1 is my button in another **ViewController**.
I have declared in Lastview that T1.text=Connection1;
but the label isn't changing when I press B1 which is my button in the other **viewcontroller**.

Comment: In your action method, `New` is an uninitialized, local variable with no connection to anything.

Comment: how to initialize it ? Thank you Anna :)

Comment: what is `Connection1`? is it setter or what else?

Comment: Connection1 is a NSstring i declared it in Lastview.h to pass data through it

Answer (score -1):

Try writing a **setter** method for the string that you need to display in your label:

In your ListView.h:

```
 @interface ListView:UIViewController 

 @property (nonatomic,strong)NSString * t1Text;

 @end
```

In your ListView.m, write the setter for your string:

```
-(void)setT1Text:(NSString *)t1Text
 {
 yourLabel.text = t1Text;
 }
```

On your Button Click do the following

```
-(IBAction)B1:(id)sender 
 {
 LastView *New ; 
 New.t1Text=@"Salut";
 }
```